# Harmonic functions and Laplace Operatos

Tags: real-analysis

Using the Laplace Operator with cylindrical coordinates in R^3, find an harmonic non trivial function defined in R^3, which is invariant for rotations along the Z-axis but without spherical symmetry. I have tried with lineal functions because I don't know many example of these types of function.

Comment: How about $f(r,\theta,z)=z$?

Comment: You are looking for a function $u=f(r,z)$, that is independent of the angular coordinate. Try this in the Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates, you can probably find a solution where the variables are separated, $f(r,z)=F(r)G(z)$